# how to prepare sql query to prevent Non-constant SQL error

Tags: c#, static-code-analysis

In below sql query construction I am sending table-name and connection-string during run time which makes me prepare query like this in C#,

```
 using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand($@"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {table} (
                                                            Name VARCHAR(250));", connection))
            {
                await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
            }
```

In static code analysis scan I am getting this as `Non-constant SQL` error and below is the suggestion,

> Use one of the following methods:Use a query-preparation API to safely construct the SQL query containing user-supplied values.Only concatenate a user-supplied value into a query if it has been checked against a whitelist of safe string values, or if it must be a Boolean or numeric type.

What this mean and how to prepare such SQL query in C#?

Comment: It means that _table_ string could be anything for what the analyzers can tell. Even a malicious string that will be injected inside your query changing its behavior to reach for some very unintended result. The search term is SQL Injection

Comment: Ok Thanks @Steve, any fix could you please suggest?

Comment: Where does `table` come from and how do you know it's safe? If you have a whitelist, you could possibly just ignore the error. If not then you need to ensure it is correctly escaped/quoted

Comment: Well, because you are building a table with an arbitrary name then you can only check if the name used contains just one word and inside that word there are no characters that could be used for sql injection. In particular check for the characters used for comments in Npgsql. They should be always present if someone attempts to do a Sql Injection

Comment: No matter what checks you include, also always escape the identifier, even if just to cover the case where the checks fail. To quote an identifier, enclose it in double quotes and double any double quotes inside the double quotes -- in less confusing terms, `@$"...""{table.Replace("\"", "\"\"")}""..."` (although the mixing of different quoting styles here is still confusing, but that's down to C#). And, of course, first make sure you need to have dynamic table names in the first place, they are most often a sign of a design error where you should have one table with an extra column.